# Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe

Tags: redis, passwords, command-line-interface, warnings

When i try to used redis cli for access redis it is showing me to Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe.what is issue here & solution?

I try redis cli command to access redis with the password but getting some waring here Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe.

Answer (score 1):

> what is issue here

With '-a', '-u' command line argument, you leave your password in command history. If others run `history` command, they can get your password of Redis. That's unsafe!

> solution?

Do not use '-a', instead, running `auth password` explicitly in `redis-cli` shell. `Auth` command does not save in Redis-cli's command history.